# Does anyone have advice for how to use inputs to determine placement into list?

Tags: python, list, input

I am writing code to identify if plants are safe or unsafe. In my code, after a user enters their plant, I want to have the user answer questions about the plant. Once they are done answering questions, they can enter another plant and repeat this process.

My goal is to have each question assigned a value; so, if the user answers "no" to all the questions, the plant is the safest, if the user answers "no" to half of them, it is half as safe. I would append plants with four or more "yeses" to safe and the other plants to "unsafe". Then, I want to define two more functions that print the safest and least safe plants using the amount of yes and nos.

Thank you to everyone who commented! I now have so many different ways I could code this. I'm very grateful for all the help!! The new edits reflect the new names of the list.

```
def plantidentifier():
  print(("Enter plant or XXX to quit "))
  plant = input().upper()
      print("Is a mushroom")
      print("Does your plant have thorns?")   
      print("Is your plant yellow or white?")
      print ("Are there shiny leaves?")
      print("Is your plant umbrella shaped?")
      Good.append(plant)
      Bad.append(plant)
      return Good, Bad

Good = []
Bad = []
print("Welcome to plant identifier!")
print("Please cafeully consider your plants")
print("Enter the name of your first plant and start answering questions. When done entering plants, enter XXX")
plantidentifier()
```

Comment: Instead of `print`, use `input` and set the value to a variable.

Comment: I would suggest defining a plant `class` which stores `boolean` values for each of the questions: `True` if the user entered yes, and `False` if they entered no. You could actually just count the number of `True`s and store that as a single variable in your plant class instead of storing the booleans. You can also override comparison operators to then sort a list of plants based on safeness.

Comment: Okay, I will do so. I am just a bit confused about how all those input statements would work.

Comment: Kraigolas, would you mind elaborating a bit? I don't really understand how that would work, but thank you for writing such a specific and helpful answer.

Comment: If you're feeling ambitious, you could use a library to convert all  `y`, `yes`, `t`, `true`, `on`, `1`, `n`, `no`, `f`, `false`, `off`, `0` into `True` and `False` for you https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/apiref.html?highlight=distutils.util#distutils.util.strtobool

Answer (score 5):

To go with my comment, here is a simple outline of what you might want to do in this situation. Notice that if you want the results for individual questions this will not work,

```
from distutils.util import strtobool

class Plant:
    max_danger_rating = 1 # The number of questions asked 

    def __init__(self):
        self.danger_rating = 0 # how many questions have been answered yes 
        is_dangerous = input("Is this plant dangerous?")
        if strtobool(is_dangerous): #here is_dangerous can be "yes", "y", "t", ...
            self.danger_rating += 1 

plants = [] # create your plants and add them to this list 

dangerous_plants  = [plant for plant in plants if plant.danger_rating > Plant.max_danger_rating / 2]
safe_plants = [plant for plant in plants if plant.danger_rating <= Plant.max_danger_rating / 2]
dangerous_plants.sort(key = lambda plant: plant.danger_rating)
```

You'll notice especially at the end that we can use the `danger_rating` as a key to sort by, which makes your work a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can

1. capture the answers in a list
2. sum the scores ('no' has a score of 1)
3. store the plant-score pair in a dictionary
4. add to SafePlants if score is >= 4
5. return SafePlants, UnsafePlants, and plant_score dictionary
6. you can print the plant-score pairs sorted by score

```
def func():
  # a dictionary to store the plant, score pair
  p_score = {}
  print(("Enter name or XXX to quit "))
  name = input().upper()
  while name != "XXX":
    if name == "" or name ==" ":
      print("no name entered")
    else:
      # put responses in a list
      response = [
          input("Is your a name a mushroom"),
          input("Does your name have shiny?"),
          input("Is your name yellow or white?"),
          input("Is your name umbrella?")
      ]
      # calculate the score, 'no' has score of 1, this sums the score of the questions
      score = sum([x=='no' for x in response])
      # store plant and score in the dictionary
      p_score[name]=score
      # add plant to good if it has score of 4 or more
      if score >=4:
          good.append(name)
      else:
          bad.append(name)

    print(("Enter name or XXX to quit "))
    name = input().upper()
  return bad, good, p_score

good = []
bad = []
print("Welcome to name identifier!")
print("Please carefully consider your names")
print("Enter the name of your first plant and start answering questions. When done entering plants, enter XXX")
bad, good, p_score=func()
# print plants with scores from unsafest to safest
print(sorted(p_score.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]))
```

Comment: Thank you! This is amazing, it appends the plants to the list and with that I think I can "rank" them. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you again, I'm just a tiny bit confused. I tried to add in a loop until the user enters "XXX" so multiple plants could be entered. I'm very sorry if this is a stupid question, but why can I not adjust the code so the loop repeats until XXX is entered?

Comment: @Julia That would be because you return at the end of the loop in the `else` statement. You can change that to `print` instead.

Comment: Thank you M Chen! You've answered so many questions, I truly appreciate it. I changed it to print, but the program just stops after one plant is entered.

Comment: @Julia you can move the return to outside of while loop. Then, you have to ask the user again for the next plant inside the while loop to get the next plant. Answer updated.

Comment: @Tim I'm so, so, sorry to bother you again, but would you mind switching just a bit more about the code in plant identifier?

Comment: @Julia sorry about the late response. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

See the comments for explanation on what I did here. This is not a great code, but hopefully it does what you want.

```py
def plantidentifier():
  print(("Enter plant or XXX to quit "))
  plant = input().upper()
  while plant != "XXX":
    if plant == "" or plant ==" ":
      print("no plant entered")
    else:  
      # Get answers from user and make them lowercase
      q1 = input("Is your a plant a mushroom\n").lower()
      q2 = input("Does your plant have shiny leaves or thorns?\n").lower()
      q3 = input("Is your plant yellow or white?\n").lower()
      q4 = input("Is your plant umbrella shaped?\n").lower()

      # put answers in a list, to operate on all of them
      answers = [q1, q2, q3, q4]
      positive_answers = 0  # this will count how many "yeses" we got
      negative_answers = 0  # this will count how many "no" we got
      for answer in positive_answers:
          if answer == "yes":
              positive_answers += 1
          elif answer == "no":
              negative_answers += 1

      # we need to use str function, because you can't add number to string (ie. "a" + 4).
      # You need to convert 4 => "4"
      print("The plant is " + str(positive_answers/negative_answers) + " safe")

      if positive_answers == SOME_NUMBER:
          SafePlants.append(plant)
      else:
          UnsafePlants.append(plant)
      # there is no "return" here, because you use global variables (SafePlants, UnsafePlants)

SafePlants = []
UnsafePlants = []
print("Welcome to plant identifier!")
print("Please cafeully consider your plants")
print("Enter the name of your first plant and start answering questions. When done entering plants, enter XXX")
plantidentifier()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possible solution:

```
import sys

# Request input and check if it equals XXX
def input_cx(msg):
    x = input(msg)
    if x.upper() == "XXX":
        sys.exit()
    return x

def plantidentifier():
  while True:
    plant = input_cx("Enter plant or XXX to quit ")
    if plant.strip() == "":
      print("no plant entered")
    else:
      inputs = []
      yes_inputs = 0
      inputs.append(input_cx("Is your a plant a mushroom"))
      inputs.append(input_cx("Does your plant have shiny leaves or thorns?"))
      inputs.append(input_cx("Is your plant yellow or white?"))
      inputs.append(input_cx("Is your plant umbrella shaped?"))
      for i in inputs:
        if i == "yes":
          yes_inputs += 1
      if yes_inputs >= 4:
        UnsafePlants.append(plant)
      else:
        SafePlants.append(plant)

SafePlants = []
UnsafePlants = []
print("Welcome to plant identifier!")
print("Please cafeully consider your plants")
print("Enter the name of your first plant and start answering questions. When done entering plants, enter XXX")
plantidentifier()
```

This first defines `input_cx` as a function that takes a string parameter. It will run the `input` function with `msg` and return the input, unless it equals `"XXX"`, in which case it will exit the program.

In the `plantidentifier` function, it runs a `while True` loop. Each iteration, it first uses `input_cx` to define the plant name. If it is not an empty value (ignoring whitespace), it will define `inputs` and `yes_inputs` as an empty list and 0 respectively. It then asks the user the 4 questions and appends each of them to `inputs`. It will then iterate over each value of `inputs` and, for each `"yes"` input, will add 1 to `yes_inputs`. If the value of `yes_inputs` comes out to be 4 or greater, the plant is appended to `UnsafePlants`; otherwise, it is appended to `SafePlants`.

Comment: Thank you! I think I'm going to use this, now that I understand how input_cx works. Just one really quick question; do you know if I can have two while loop, so until the user enters XXX you can keep inputting plants? I've tried to do this on two sets of code and I'm a bit concerned it's not possible.

Comment: @Julia I don't know exactly what you mean. The current workflow is: program asks for a plant, asks 4 questions, evaluates plant safety, repeats, if any input is XXX immediately exits the program. Do you want all the plants to be entered when you first run the code, and then ask the questions for each plant?

Comment: Oh no, I must have worded it wrong. I was hoping to be able to enter a plant, answer question, then enter another plant, answer questions, etc until XXX was entered and the program ends.

Comment: @Julia the code should be doing exactly that - the loop iterates indefinitely, and it will request input for `plant`'s name and ask the plant's relevant questions each iteration. All inputs are taken with `input_cx`, which terminates the program if the input is "XXX"; otherwise the loop should keep iterating forever.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing, you can do this:

```
results_list.append(True if input("Does your plant have this quality?").upper() == "TRUE" else False)
```

This uses Python's ternary operator, which is useful to know about.

As Galunid suggested, you can also do this:

```
results_list.append(input("Does your plant have this quality?").upper() == "TRUE")
```

since this will add a boolean.

Both check case-insensitively whether the input is `"TRUE"` (obviously in your case, you may want to check more than just that) and adds `True` to `results_list` if so and `False` if not. If you want to check more than just `"TRUE"` I suggest assigning the input to a variable like so: `var = input("Foo")`.

Then, you can just check the `count` of `True` in `results_list` to determine whether the plant is safe!

Below is the working version, with a typo fixed and the results printed:

```py
def plantidentifier():
  print(("Enter plant or XXX to quit "))
  plant = input().upper()
  while plant != "XXX":
    if plant == "" or plant ==" ":
        print("no plant entered")
    else:
        results_list = []       
        results_list.append(input("Is your a plant a mushroom").upper() == "TRUE")
        results_list.append(input("Does your plant have shiny leaves or thorns?").upper() == "TRUE")
        results_list.append(input("Is your plant yellow or white?").upper() == "TRUE")
        results_list.append(input("Is your plant umbrella shaped?").upper() == "TRUE")
        if results_list.count(True) > 2:
            Good.append(plant)
        else:
            Bad.append(plant)
        return Bad, Good

Good = []
Bad = []
print("Welcome to plant identifier!")
print("Please carefully consider your plants")
print("Enter the name of your first plant and start answering questions. When done entering plants, enter XXX")
print(plantidentifier())
```

Comment: Thank you! This is amazing, I didn't even know you could do that.

Comment: You don't need `if-else` when appending to the list. `input("Is your a plant a mushroom").upper() == "TRUE"` will return either `True/False`

Comment: @Galunid GREAT advice!! I didn't think of that. I'll update my answer.